# Can I set bounty on a question? How?

Tags: support, bounty

I'm new to stackoverflow. Do I have enough karma to offer bounty on a question? How do I do this?

Comment: See the official Stack Overflow/Server Fault/Super User (SOFU) FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/the-official-faq-for-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user, and then link from there to the bounty discussion at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work-in-stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [FAQ link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067) reemrevnivek provided, only questions older than 2 days are eligible for a bounty. So far, no such questions exist, so you will not see the option.